# how to import column(s) of data from TABLE customer to TABLE order and inserting additional data into TABLE order

Tags: sql-server, database

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
CustID int IDENTITY(1,1) ,
customerNo AS 'C' + CAST(CustID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
customerName varchar(50),
customerStreet varchar(20),
customerCity varchar(50),
customerState varchar(50),
customerZIPCode varchar(20),
customerTelNo varchar(50),
custFaxNo varchar(50),
DOB varchar(50),
maritalStatus varchar(50),
creditRating varchar(50),
)
```

```sql
INSERT INTO Customer (customerName, customerStreet, customerCity, customerState, customerZIPCode, customerTelNo, custFaxNo, DOB, maritalStatus, creditRating)
VALUES ('Ana A.', '10', 'Charlotte', 'North Carolina', '28205', '+655 323 4545', '+655 323 4546', '16-02-1975', 'Married', '90%')
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmpID int IDENTITY(1,1) ,
employeeNo AS 'E' + CAST(EmpID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar(10),
firstName varchar(50),
middleName varchar(50),
lastName varchar(50),
address varchar(100),
workTelExt varchar(50),
homeTelNo varchar(50),
empEmailAddress varchar(50),
socialSecurityNumber varchar(50),
DOB varchar(50),
position varchar(50),
sex varchar(20),
salary varchar(20),
dateStarted varchar(20),
)
```

```sql
INSERT INTO Employee (title, firstName, middleName, lastName, address, workTelExt, homeTelNo, empEmailAddress, socialSecurityNumber, DOB, position, sex, salary, dateStarted)
VALUES ('Ms', 'Ana', 'A', 'Daven', '11, Charlotte, North Carolina, 28205', '+655 856 9786', '+655 374 4639', 'Ana.Daven@nc.co.com', 'A5403B32', '16-10-1975', 'Senior Officer', 'Female', '$4000', 'Jan 2001')
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Orders
( 
EmpID int IDENTITY(1,1),
orderNo AS 'E' + CAST(EmpID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
orderDate varchar(20),
billingStreet varchar(50),
billingCity varchar(50),
billingState varchar(50),
billingZipCode varchar(50),
promisedDate varchar(20),
status varchar(20),
customerNo varchar(11),
employeeNo varchar(11),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerCustomer FOREIGN KEY (customerNo)
REFERENCES Customer(customerNo),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerEmployee FOREIGN KEY (employeeNo)
REFERENCES Employee(employeeNo)
)
```

"what statement to use in order to IMPORT customerNo and employeeNo. at the same time INSERTING VALUES to the (orderDate, billingStreet, billingCity, billingState, billingZipCode, promisedDate, status)" in single row of data?

Comment: how do i create a data with both Foreign Key and inserting VALUES at the same time to a SINGLE ROW OF DATA

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp ?

Comment: Nope not this.. Sorry to ask silly question but I'm new to sql. Is it even possible to insert value of Foreign Key without keying it in the VALUES()? Can it be grab automatically?